# Tax calculation showing wrong in magento2

Tags: tax, shopping-cart, tax-calculation, tax-rounding

Total is 607.77 and TAX is 6%,  it's 36.4662

But magento showing 37.67

[image]

Can anyone help me how i can get 36.4662 insted 37.67?

**Admin side tax settings:**

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Could you please add your tax calculation settings in the admin?

Comment: Also, could you please also explain how state and county tax are distributed?

Comment: @RishabhDwivedi, Please review admin settings.

Comment: I reviewed your calculation settings and according to it prices displayed are correct. Let me explain, you have a 6% tax applicable on "Total" and the breakdown is as follows:
Subtotal: 607.77
Total would be Subtotal + Shipping Price = 607.77 + 20 = 627.77
6% tax on subtotal is (State Tax + County Tax) = 607.77 * 6% = 36.47
6% tax on shipping price is = 20 * 6% = 1.20
So the total tax applicable is 627.77 * 6% = 37.662 (approx 37.67) OR 36.47+ 1.20 =  37.67. You are calculating the tax on subtotal instead of total that's why it seems wrong to you. Let me know if you have any doubt

Answer (score 1):

Taxes are displayed correctly. According to the calculation setting taxes are being calculated on **Total**.
Let me explain, you have a 6% tax applicable on "Total" and the breakdown is as follows:

- Subtotal: **607.77**
- Total would be (Subtotal + Shipping Price):
  **607.77 + 20 = 627.77**
- 6% tax on subtotal is (State Tax + County Tax): **607.77 * 6% = 36.47**
- 6% tax on shipping price is: 20 * 6% = 1.20
- So the total tax applicable is **627.77 * 6% = 37.662 (approx 37.67)** OR if you add up all the taxes **36.47+ 1.20 =  37.67.**

You are calculating the tax on subtotal instead of total that's what confusing you. There are a couple of things you can do here:

- If taxes displayed against state, county, and shipping are correct then you can subtract the tax amount of shipping from the total tax and display the remaining amount which would be in this case **37.7 - 1.20**.
- If you do not want to apply the tax on shipping then you can go to the tax calculation setting in the backend and set the shipping price to "including tax" but this will make Magento assume that the shipping price already has tax applied to it and this will stop showing tax applied to the shipping price.
- You can add an additional row in the summary block where you can specify "Tax applied on subtotal" and display **37.7 - 1.20** along with the Total tax, it will give a clear picture of the actual calculations.

I think the problem is in the representation instead of calculations since I am not aware of your client's requirements and your customizations, these are the only suggestions I can provide.

Comment: Is there any way to get 36.4662 instead 37.67? TaxJar is used for tax calculation.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please free to reach out to me in case of any queries. We can discuss this as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to select "None" for the"Tax Class for Shipping"  setting[image]

Comment: It's already none.